# Heap Overload JVM

Tags: java, heap-memory, overflow, inputstream

EDIT***: As it stands right now, I have a program that is getting caught in an infinite loop somehow, but im not sure what is causing it. My program reads in data from a text file and essentially "saws off" the first section of data on each line until the first occurrence of a ',' character, and then reads each subsequent string (terminated by a ' ' in the general case) until the next ',' (special case, indicating that the following data is also junk). From there, it skips down to the next line and repeats. My program was working fine a few weeks ago but I tinkered with it and now it is officially broken. Below this edit are some of the other errors I ran into (that I may still need to address) but at the moment, I am being killed by this loop somewhere. I admittedly have a knack for screwing myself with nested FOR loops, and for using funky iterators and updates, but this one I just can't crack. Here is the code, with some explanation. This entire snippet is just thrown into the constructor for some arbitrary class taking a string "synsets" and an instance is being created in my main. The rest I have commented as best possible:

```
    In in = new In(synsets); // Custom input stream class, courtesy 
    // of Princeton U
    Out fout = new Out("log.txt"); // ostream analogue

    int linecount=0; // Marker used to keep track of line # in input file
    int nouncount=0; // Marker for keeping track of the number of 
    // "important" data items

    // Data comes in the format: 
    // "junk,important important important,junk
    // junk,important,junk
    // junk,important important,junk" etc.

    {
        int i=0;
        for ( String str=in.readLine();str!=null;str=in.readLine() )
        {
            i=0; // reset iterator for a new line
            for ( char next=str.charAt(i); next!=',';next=str.charAt(i) )
                i++; // This FOR loop cuts out the junk at the start of 
                     // a line
            i++; // increment to after first comma
            for ( char next=str.charAt(i);next!=',';next=str.charAt(i))
            {
                for (; next!=',' && next!=' ' ;next=str.charAt(i))
                {
                    i++;
                    fout.print(next);
                    // count the "nouns" (important data) on a line
                }
                nouncount++; 
                // count the last noun on line, and subsequently fall 
                // through loops to skip the rest of the junk at the 
                // current line
                fout.print('\n');
            }

        }
        fout.print(nouncount);
        in.close();
```

My output file is fine, until line 18 of the input, at which point it just begins print new line characters (like its caught on the loop which appends them but cant fall through to the next loop). Here are the input lines in question. It reads 24-karat_gold just fine, but isn't making it to pure_gold for some reason. Any thoughts? Thanks yall!

"17,24-karat_gold pure_gold,100 per cent gold
18,24/7,uptime is 24 hours a day 7 days a week"

EDIT*: I was coding a program to read in some data from a text file and got a new (to me) error message that I had run out of heap space. I tried tinkering to fix the bug, but only succeeded in getting rid of the error message. The text file I was reading from is about 90K lines, but my program threw the message at line 18. My tinkering did reveal some things, particularly, that my program was at least able to do SOME processing on the file as a whole, and that the issue may have involved some data corruption. The reason I deduced this was because of an array index I was using "j" which was firing off an IndexOutOfBoundsException. The problem, j only scaled by 1 each time it was incremented, and somehow, it was (is) going out of bounds over 150,000 higher than the array's bounds. Thus, it is my assumption that "j" is somehow being filled with data (possibly because the stack is overwriting into the heap?) which has nothing to do with "j" or the array in question. Below is my original post, though I was admittedly pretty tired, so it may not make a whole lot of sense. THANKS YALL! :)

EDIT**: I did a check of nouncount, and it is 399850, so I wasn't experiencing data corruption, as I had suspected. One of my loops is just executing ad infinitum. I'll try to figure out which one and post back if I can correct the problem. I'll at least be back to clean up this post a bit for anyone in need in the future.

Im writing a program that reads in a text file and it has to do some counting (the data in the file is divided up in a very syntactic way) but my code isn't able to get very far. While the file is pretty substantial (around 90K lines) my code is only getting through 17 before I get heap overflow.

Some background, the "In" class is just a specialized input stream, and what is actually killing me is not the first FOR loop, where I count the lines (the code executes this portion just fine, reading in every line individually, each once). Rather, it is the second part, but I don't understand, because I am not using any additional heap space (I thought?) in that portion. I previously had the blocks together, doing the major functions together on a line-by-line basis, but again, the program would stop at line 17. I tried allocating up to a GB of heap space in Dr Java, but to no avail. Is there any section in the lower half in which I could set aside additional heap space?

```
        In in = new In(synsets);

    StringBuilder nounData = new StringBuilder();
    int linecount=0;
    int nouncount=0;

    {
        String str;
        int i=0;
        char next='\0';
        for ( str=in.readLine();str!=null;str=in.readLine() )
        {
            linecount++;
        }
        in.close();

        in = new In(synsets);
        for ( str=in.readLine();str!=null;str=in.readLine() )
        {
            i=0;
// The first portion of each line is "trash" until the first comma
            for ( next=str.charAt(i) ; next!=',' ; next=str.charAt(++i) ){}
            i++;

// This actually reads/processes the data until the next comma, then
// jumps to the next line. "What" i need done is really secondary, I 
// just need to figure out what is eating so much space so I can 
// trim it
            for ( next=str.charAt(i);next!=',';next=str.charAt(i))
                for (;next!=','&&next!=' ';next=str.charAt(++i))
                nouncount++;
        }
    }
```

Here is the updated code, wherein I tried to recreate the Heap message from Dr Java. While I couldnt do that, I did get an interesting error message (at line 18 of course) about an array out of bounds. Still stumped though, as I dont see how the variable in question could be more than 17 at the time it gets hit.

Here is the code:

```
In in = new In(synsets);

    StringBuilder nounData = new StringBuilder();
    int linecount=0;
    int nouncount=0;

    {
        int i=0;
        for ( String str=in.readLine();str!=null;str=in.readLine() )
        {
            i=0;
            for ( char next=str.charAt(i);next!=',';next=str.charAt(i))
                for (;next!=','&&next!=' ';next=str.charAt(++i))
                nouncount++;
        }
        in.close();
        in=new In(synsets);

        String[] nouns = new String[nouncount];
        int j=0;
        for ( String str=in.readLine();str!=null;str=in.readLine() )
        {
            linecount++;
            i=0;
            for ( char next=str.charAt(i) ; next!=',' ; next=str.charAt(++i) ){}
            i++;
            for ( char next=str.charAt(i);next!=',';next=str.charAt(i))
            {
                for (;next!=','&&next!=' ';next=str.charAt(++i))
                    nounData.append(next);
                nouns[j++]=nounData.toString();
                nounData.delete(0,nounData.capacity()-1);
            }
            System.out.println("Current line count is: " + linecount);
        }
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println("line count = "+linecount);
    System.out.println("noun count = "+nouncount);
    String[] nouns = new String[nouncount];
```

and here is the error message:

```
Current line count is: 1
Current line count is: 2
Current line count is: 3
Current line count is: 4
Current line count is: 5
Current line count is: 6
Current line count is: 7
Current line count is: 8
Current line count is: 9
Current line count is: 10
Current line count is: 11
Current line count is: 12
Current line count is: 13
Current line count is: 14
Current line count is: 15
Current line count is: 16
Current line count is: 17
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 399850
    at WordNet.<init>(WordNet.java:39)
    at WordNet.main(WordNet.java:212)
```

For the record, line "39" in my code is:

```
nouns[j++]=nounData.toString();
```

Character count in the file up until line 18 is 917, at line 19 it is 966, so i dont think I misplaced that line.

EDIT: Furthermore, I did a test, and there are only about 147K "nouns" in the file, so my guess is that "j" is being corrupted somehow, seeing as how it must have had to have "jumped" from something between 0 and 147K to 399K+. Unfortunately, its past my bedtime, so I shan't be able to continue updating tonight but feel free to post any ideas, Ill be checking via email tomorrow morning :) Thanks everyone!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "heap overflow" and you don't appear to be retaining any objects in memory so you shouldn't be using too much heap.  It is more likely you are not reading the error message correctly.  Can you post it here so wre can see what it is .  Can you include which line it occurs on.

Comment: I actually don't have any error messages, but when my code was condensed, I got the heap notifcation. rather, If I put some sort of print command in the second FOR chunk, it gets stuck indefinitely at the 18th line, where I was previously getting the heap message. Ill see if I cant recreate the message though, one moment.

Comment: @user3118524 Is that the `in = new In(synsets);` line after `in.close()`?

Comment: You should be able to read your error messages or writing your program will be very hard as you will be forced to guess what is wrong.  You should also be able to debug your program as this is the quickest way to find errors.

Comment: Hahaha i can interpret error messages just fine, I'm literally not getting any when I compile and run this, it just gets "stuck" after line 17. It looks like its processing something, but my machine isn't slowed down at all. 

I don't think its the re-defining of "in", as the program did the same thing when I had all the code in one chunk. Im trying to recreate the heap overload message now. I never realized how hard it could be to force an error message.

Comment: It seems I cant edit my previous comment, but I didn't mean to sound patronizing, Peter. I agree with you totally, and I can assume that you deal with more than your share of people who don't bother to read error messages, and so I can absolutely understand where you are coming from. Just wanted to let you know that I am thankful that you are at least looking into my plight, and that you are willing to offer advice at all. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Change all of your `for` test conditions

```
next!=','
```

to

```
next != ',' && i < str.length()
```

except your last one,

```
for (;next!=','&&next!=' ';next=str.charAt(++i))
```

which should be

```
for (;next!=','&&next!=' '&&i+1<str.length();next=str.charAt(++i))
```

Next, I would try to [`String.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String[] words = str.split(",\\s+);
```

and you could get the word count with `words.length`. To get a line count, increment a counter when you call `readLine()` like

```
in = new In(synsets);
// for ( str=in.readLine();str!=null;str=in.readLine() )
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    linecount++;
    String[] words = str.split(",\\s+);
    nouncount += words.length;
}
```

Comment: In other words, most likely the OP has an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException which has nothing to do with the heap size or an overflow of the stack.

Comment: Im gonna try these and see what I can whip up. I wasn't getting any exceptions, though.

EDIT: Also, I can't directly count words, there is a lot of "trash" in the file, both at the beginning and end of lines, so I need to specifically count the words I need (positioned between the first and second comma of each line).

Comment: I havent yet gotten to add in your edits, but I certainly shall tomorrow. Thanks again, Elliott.

Comment: Upon further review, I think you may be on to something. If my "noun-counter" isn't functioning properly, I may not be experiencing heap "overflow" at all, and my "j" index may not be "jumping" as I first suspected. I realized in retrospect, that j is an int, and thus 4 bytes, and so data corruption would (probabilistically speaking) lead to a number much higher than 400K, being most likely closer to the upper bound of what ints can store.

Comment: The only way I could see data corruption happening and giving values so low is that j is at the top of the heap, and the damage is only happening two (or three?) bytes into the heap. Im going to run some more tests when I get home. Thanks again!